# Newline URL entity when using esc_url()

Tags: urls

Is it possible to set a newline character `\n` as a URL entity when using `esc_url()`? The URL entity for a newline is `%0A` as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871729/transmitting-newline-character-n

But `esc_url()` strips out the `%0A`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background:

WordPress strips out `%0A` from URL because in general newline has no practical purpose in URL. Unless it's a `mailto:` protocol, [WordPress strips out `%0A`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.7.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3775).

So it's better not to use them in URL at all.

## Solution:

Still, if for any specific purpose you have to use `%0A`, you may use `%250A` and then filter it back to `%0A` using `clean_url` filter.

> `%250A` is URL encoded version of `%0A`, i.e. double URL encoded version of `newline`.

You may use the following CODE for filtering (in a plugin or in your active theme's `functions.php` file):

```
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'double_encoded_nl_to_encoded_nl' );
function double_encoded_nl_to_encoded_nl( $url ) {
    return str_ireplace( '%250A', '%0A', $url );
}
```

Now, this: `esc_url( "http://example.com/?q=foo%250Abar" );` will return `http://example.com/?q=foo%0Abar`.